# CMU Sphinx: Voxforge german model - no accuracy

Tags: java, cmusphinx

I am trying to use CMU Sphinx 4 with the german VoxForge model from [here](http://goofy.zamia.org/voxforge/de/).

I am using Java because it doesn't work in C++ for some reason (altough I would prefer C++; maybe someone can help me with this too?).

When I run my program I get a bunch of warnings like this: "WARNING largeTrigramMode  The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'LAMPEN'".

After that I get a wrong output. I a trying to recognize a 16000Hz, mono .WAV-file in which I say "Eins Zwei Drei Test" (One, two, three, test). But my program writes "EINS ZENTRALE FRAGE DER LÜFTE" into the console.

I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find any help to my problem. Does someone here have a solution?

Comment: You need to provide more information on what exactly models (specifically, language model) are you using. You also need to share the voice sample you are trying to recognize. You definitely need to improve both acoustic and language model, language model first. Acoustic model should be reasonably good already.

Comment: And, such questions are better discussed on sourceforge forum, they are not really about programming